# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in release version

Tags: java, android

I have made an android app
in debugging mode the app had no issues ,
but after release and apk file .
I got crash reports from google play users

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setDataSource(Landroid/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor;)V in class Landroid/media/MediaPlayer; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.media.MediaPlayer' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
at com.ali.gunprank.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

and the gradle file is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias ******
     keyPassword ******
}
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ali.gunprank"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

so any one have any Idea what should I do ?

Comment: Probably you should understand the differences between the various API levels of the Android libraries. You can't just use anything and assume it works the same way for all versions of Android.

Comment: Please post here your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Post the entire file updating your question please.

Comment: If you get NoSuchMethod in release but not debug, and if you are using proguard, first check your proguard config.  It could be stripping or renaming methods.  If anything is trying to call these methods by reflection, you will get this error.